# How can I do a compare with space omitted in a LINQ where?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ Where clause:

```
 var ext = extendedPhrases
            .Where(x => x.HepburnRomaji != x.Romaji && x.Romaji != null);
```

Is there a way that I can remove spaces from x.Romaji so that I can compare HephurnRomaji with x.Romaji that has no spaces between characters?

Comment: I would swap the two comparisons. Null-check is very fast and can be cleared in less CPU-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make null-check condition first. Otherwise you will have `NullReferenceException` on removing whitespaces from string.
2. Use [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove whitespaces from Romaji

Code

```
var ext = extendedPhrases
   .Where(x => x.Romaji != null && x.HepburnRomaji != x.Romaji.Replace(" ", ""));
```

Comment: In my code I have been chaing .RegexReplace("ア", "あ") after a string like this to do replacements.  Is there any difference between String.Replace and RegexReplace?

Comment: @Anne when you do simple string replacement then String.Replace will be the fasted option. Use Regex.Replace when you need to match some pattern or you need to execute some logic when doing replacement

Answer (score 2):

change

```
.Where(x => x.HepburnRomaji != x.Romaji && x.Romaji != null);
```

into

```
.Where(x => x.Romaji != null && x.HepburnRomaji != x.Romaji.Replace(" ",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

An obvious choice is to use `Replace`. However, it creates new objects for each string that has spaces. If you would like to avoid new object creation, use [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
Where(x =>
    x.Romaji != null
&& !x.HepburnRomaji.SequenceEqual(x.Romaji.Where(c => c != ' ')
)
```